# Is the following proof of division algorithm correct?

Tags: number-theory

> **Theorem:** Let $b$ denote a fixed positive integer. Then, for every integer $n\ge0$, there exist nonnegative integers $q$ and $r$ such that 
>   $n=qb+r$ , $0\le r<b$.

**Proof:** *Base case:* For $n=0$ we find that $q=0$ and $r=0$.

*Inductive step:* $n=qb+r$ $\Rightarrow$ $n+1=qb+r+1$. We can split the inductive step into following two cases:

$(i)$ $0\le r<b-1$

$(ii)$ $r=b-1$.

It is already obvious that $r$ cannot exceed $b-1$.

In the first case, new remainder is $r+1$ and $q$ stays the same. In second case, new quotient is $q+1$ and new remainder is $0$.

This shows that the theorem is valid for every $n\ge 0$.

Comment: The proof is good.

Comment: Other versions of the proof can be shared in answers, if any.

Comment: A standard proof goes like this. Let $S$ be the set of all non-negative integers of the form $n-xb$, where $x$ ranges over the non-negative integers. Then $S$ has a smallest element. Call it $r$. Now argue that $r\lt b$.

Comment: This way is more compact. Thanks.

Comment: The main pedagogical reason for the least element proof is that the same structure is used to prove that the gcd of $a$ and $b$ is an integer linear combination of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: You could use a couple of equations to complete the steps for case (ii): $$r=b-1 \implies n+1 = qb+b = (q+1)b = (q+1)b+0$$ which is in the form required.

Comment: Yes, it would be more clear.